# Heroku malformed Procfile (using their own example)

Tags: heroku

I'm working through the Getting started with Django series and am running into a problem with Heroku.

I've worked through the steps time after time again, running in a provided VM with Virtualenv set up. When I do a `git push heroku master`, I get the following output:

```
(blog-venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/projects/microblog$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 3.61 KiB, done.
Total 11 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Python app detected
-----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.3.
-----> Preparing Python runtime (python-2.7.3)
-----> Installing Distribute (0.6.34)
-----> Installing Pip (1.2.1)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.2.1)
       Downloading/unpacking Django==1.4.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package Django

       Downloading/unpacking argparse==1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package argparse

           no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'env24'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'env25'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'env26'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'env27'
       Installing collected packages: Django, argparse
         Running setup.py install for Django
           changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/django-admin.py from 600 to 755

           changing mode of /app/.heroku/python/bin/django-admin.py to 755
         Running setup.py install for argparse

           no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'env24'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'env25'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'env26'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'env27'
       Successfully installed Django argparse
       Cleaning up...
-----> Collecting static files
       0 static files copied.

-----> Discovering process types

 !     This format of Procfile is unsupported
 !     Use a colon to separate the process name from the command
 !     e.g.   python:  manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT .noreload

 !     Heroku push rejected, malformed Procfile

To git@heroku.com:quiet-lowlands-3777.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:quiet-lowlands-3777.git'
(blog-venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/projects/microblog$ cat Procfile
python: manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload
```

I'm getting slightly desperate, can anyone shed some light ons this? Google etc has been done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out by now, the tutorial on: http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com is unclear on this matter. The contents of your Procfile should be:

web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload

NOT

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload

Leaving this question up for future reference for other people.

Comment: Hey, glad you solved it! There is also the [article on Profiles at heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile). Since this solved your answer you should click on the checkmark icon to denote the answer as 'accepted' :) Then other people will be able to see your answer has been solved ([see the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)). Glad it worked!